# Hybrid Control Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Iam creating a hybrid control with adding html control dynamically in login.cs file

code for `login.cs`

```
namespace WebApplication6
{
    public class LoginStandards: CompositeControl
    {
        private TextBox txtusername;
        private TextBox txtpassword;
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return txtusername.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            txtpassword.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return txtpassword.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            txtpassword.Text = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        txtusername = new TextBox();
        txtusername.ID = "txtusername";
        this.Controls.Add(txtusername);

        txtpassword = new TextBox();
        txtpassword.ID = "txtPassword";
        txtpassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
        this.Controls.Add(txtpassword);
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddStyleAttribute("float", "left");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Padding, "3px");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.For, txtusername.ClientID);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Label);
        writer.Write("User Name:");
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();

        writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Padding, "3px");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.For, txtpassword.ClientID);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Label);
        writer.Write("Password:");
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();

        writer.AddStyleAttribute("float", "left");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Padding, "3px");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        txtusername.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();

        writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Padding, "3px");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
        txtpassword.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.Write("<br style=’clear:left’ />");
    }

        protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
        {
            get
                {
                return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div;
                }
            }
}
}
```

i want to use this cs file in normal .aspx page.. i did by creating a object.. but it doesnt work.. 
how to call login.cs file in .aspx page.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "it does not works" ... what is the error / pb you encounter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/c76dd5k1.aspx) the control prefix ?

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="My"
   namespace="WebApplication6"
   assembly="WebApplication6" %>
```

Then you can use within you code:

```
<my:LoginStandards runat="server" />
```